# What does "up" mean in this phrase? "a long skirt with a slit up the side"

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

> a long skirt with a slit **up** the side

What does "up" mean in this phrase from [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/slit_1?q=slit)?

Does the sentence still mean the same if I replace "up" with "on"?

Comment: _Up_ means that the slit starts at the hem and goes upwards.

Answer (score 1):

> A long skirt with a slit up the side

versus

> A long skirt with a slit on the side.

While the two constructs are apparently reasonably similar, the first is standard usage and would pass without notice if used, whereas " ... on the side" would be almost never used and would be liable to be noticed as unusual.

In other cases on & up may be somewhat more interchangeably used. eg.

There was a pipe up the side of the building.
There was a pipe on the side of the building.

Either might be used. "... running up" would be more usual.

Comment: I would use "with a slit **on** the side." Sounds perfectly idiomatic to me.

Comment: @EliHarold Sadly, nobody else has answered or commented so other opinions are lacking. I'm in NZ - we speak 'modified Queen's English'. I consider that my answer addresses what I would expect here and I'd have expected the same in the US.

Comment: Understandable, just wanted to add that in case other readers prefer "on" and are in the US. We also would use "slit up the side" but it sounds less formal and slightly southern.

Comment: to me a "slit up the side" gives the impression of a longer slit than "on the side" does

Comment: @EliHarold (I'm also from the U.S.) To me, "slit up the side" sounds like the more idiomatic terminology for/from the clothing/fashion industry that a woman would search for when shopping for such a dress online or describing it to her girlfriends; whereas "slit on the side" is something I might expect to hear "Joe Sixpack" say when describing a dress his girlfriend wore.